# android: How to test input method editor?

Tags: keyboard, android-input-method

I have a basic implementation of the Android [InputMethodService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html) which I am trying to write unit tests for. My application does not have any Activites, just the implementation of [InputMethodService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html).

So far I have a basic implementation of a ServiceTestCase which is working great